# Video files show incorrect video

Tags: filesystems, file-management

I had a drive fail a while back. While it was failing, I made a back up to another drive. Now when I try to access those files (they are video files), the video played is a segment from another video file. Is this caused by the failing of the other drive? Perhaps the files were crosslinked?

What happened and is there a way to recover the lost files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had a drive fail a while back. While it was failing, I made a back
>   up to another drive. Now when I try to access those files (they are
>   video files), the video played is a segment from another video file.

Sadly, the file table on the other, failing drive was probably screwed up. So when you copied the files you discovered that you have what you have now; a mix of bits and pieces from files thrown together randomly.

If you somehow still have the old, failing drive and can attempt to repair the file system then that is the only real way to recover the files. But if all you have are these mixed up files, sadly that’s all you have anymore.